# Android studio insert empty imageview

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to insert an empty imageview in Android studio? when I try to add one to my layout it asks me to pick an image and if I don't pick one it doesn't seem to add the imageview.

I can add the imageview with an image and then later delete said image but that seems a rather hacky approach.

(I intend to fill in the imageview from code with an image acquired at runtime)

Comment: You can also insert image view programmatically like this

ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
// or you can  put bitmap
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

then insert this imageView in you layout like 

LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.Id.yourImageViewContainerLaylout);

ll.addView(iv);

Answer (score 1):

When you add an ImageView, choose any image. Then, go to your XML file and delete attribute with the image. Probably it would be `app:srcCompat`

Answer (score 0):

As you want to set the image on run-time, you can use setImageResource() method of Image view to do that. In your activity's on Create method, first get the instance of view.

`ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.Id.yourImageViewId);`

After that, set the desired image to it.

`imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);`